# Always show menu even in unfocused windows

Tags: unity, menu-bar

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. Recently I found out, that I can enable to always show the menu in the title bar of a window by using this console command:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity always-show-menus true
```

This works great, but right now only the menu of the focused window is shown. Is there a way to always show the menu of a window, even if it isn't focused?

Comment: try http://askubuntu.com/questions/655668/dedicated-menu-bar-inside-a-window-in-ubuntu-15-04-with-unity?rq=1