# Dedicated menu bar inside a window in Ubuntu 15.04 with Unity

Tags: unity, 15.04, menu-bar

Does somebody know how to configure Ubuntu 15.04 with Unity to show menu bars inside a window without covering the window title?

I know it is possible to display the menu bar inside the title bar without hiding it. But in this case the window title is covert. What I need is a own, dedicated menu bar inside a window that is always displayed without covering the window title - the proven old school style.

Comment: Haven't tried this myself http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/11/unity-trusty-global-menu-switch

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Install the following packages and restart your apps:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove appmenu-gtk appmenu-gtk3 appmenu-qt
```

NOTE: In Firefox, you have to disable "Global Menu Bar integration" extension as well.

Source and full documentation:

[How to Disable Ubuntu's Annoying Global Menu Bar](http://lifehacker.com/5887462/how-to-disable-ubuntus-annoying-global-menu-bar)